# QTreeWidget not displaying first item in a QList

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I'm trying to display items in a QList on a QTreeWidget but no matter how hard i tried i observe that always the first item in the List is not inserted on the treeWidget.
Please i need help. Below is my sample code

```
 void Results::showResults (QList<Semester*>* sList){
     for(int i=0; i<sList->count(); i++)
     {
           ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(sList->at(i)->treeItem);
     }  
     this->show ();
 }
```

**NB:** every Semester item in the list has a treeItem member.

Comment: Are `semList` and `sList` different lists?

Comment: I meant sList instead if semList so i've edited it.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this code.  Can you add debug to the loop to confirm that the first entry is what you think it should be (to eliminate the `QTreeWidget` itself as the cause)?

Comment: Are you sure, that first item is valid?

Comment: yeah. And when i add items starting from the back of the list, the item at index(0) is still not added

Comment: Please, provide minimal sample that reproduce this issue.